# How to generate 5555_664654 random number in php

Tags: php

I want to generate random number using php.
Number should be with underscore. Underscore should be between to numbers.No Space there between number and underscore

**input**

```
<?php

$rand = rand(0000, 9999);
$rand1 = rand(000000000, 999999999);

echo "$rand _ $rand1";

?>
```

**output**

582 _ 637878052

**I want to remove space between numbers and underscore**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using curly braces around variables in quotes helps set where they start and end. It's called variable interpolation:

```
echo "{$rand}_{$rand1}";
```

Or there is concatenation as others have pointed out:

```
echo $rand . '_' . $rand1;
```

Answer (score 1):

`echo "{$rand}_{$rand1}";`
check it online https://www.phprun.org/G521kb

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "{$rand}_{$rand1}";
```

or

```
echo $rand."_".$rand1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simple do concrete string like this

```
   echo $rand."_".$rand1;
```